# How to set cursor position for UITextView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

We are doing a validation in a `UITableViewCell`. The cell has a `textView` and a custom button on clicking which a pop over containing a `UIDatePickerView` should open & the user will select the date. Here selecting the date is mandatory. So we did a validation using the below code. In the `textViewBeginEditing` delegate method of the `textView` inside the cell in the immediate next row. i.e when the user clicks on the `textView` in the next row the previous row values will be validated.
Here the validation seems to be working but the cursor still blinks in current cell and do not move to the previous cell that is being validated.

```
UITableViewCell* myCell = (UITableViewCell*)textView.superview ;

UITextView *txtviewMycelltext;//=[[UITextView alloc]init];

for (UIView *view in myCell.subviews) 
{

  if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) 
  {

      UILabel *lbl=view;
      lbl.text=[lbl.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
      int tablerowindex=[lbl.text intValue];
      NSLog(@"%@",lbl.text);
      break;
  }
  if([view isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) 
  {
      txtviewMycelltext=view;
  }
}



inttablerowindex-=1;

if(inttablerowindex>0)
{
  if([[arrActionvalues objectAtIndex:inttablerowindex1]objectForKey:KEY_FOLLOWUPDATE]==EMPTYSTRING)
  {
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                        initWithTitle: @"Alert"
                                        message: ALERT_FOLLOWUPDATE
                                        delegate: nil
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alert show];


//              UITableView *mytable=(UITableView *)((textView.superview).superview).superview;
      UITableView *myTable=(UITableView*)[[myCell superview]superview];

      NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath*)[myTable indexPathForCell:  
          (UITableViewCell*)textView.superview.superview];
      UITableViewCell *previousCell = (UITableViewCell*)[myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row - 1 inSection:indexPath.section]];

      for (UIView *view in previousCell.subviews) 
      {
                      NSLog(@"%@",view);
                      if([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {

                          UIView *subView=view;
                          for(UIView *view2 in subView.subviews)
                          {

                              if([view2 isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
                                  UITextView *txt=view2;

                                  [txtviewMycelltext resignFirstResponder];
                                  [txt becomeFirstResponder];
                                   break;
                              }
                          }


                      }
                  }
              }
          }
```

Please let me know what needs to be done to get the cursor position to the correct cell.

Comment: This is one case where I would recommend the use of <shudder> tags </shudder>

Comment: What exactly are you validating? Your code mainly iterates through views rather clumsily...

Comment: im trying to validate whether the user has selected the date in the current cell. if he has not the set the cursor position to the row in which he has to select the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear from you code, but, I am guessing you are performing your validations inside `textViewDidEndEditing`.

`textViewShouldEndEditing` is the appropriate delegate method to perform validation of the text view contents. You can return NO if you want to prevent the switching of focus from the current text view.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewShouldEndEditing:

Comment: Thanks!!!, Changing the delegate method as textViewSHouldBeginEditing instead of textViewDidBeginEditing made the code work as per our requirement... Once again thanks.. Apart from that, jus to know, is there any way that we can set the cursor to one control???

Comment: `becomeFirstResponder` is the way to do this. But, it usually doesn't work inside delegate methods which themselves are triggered by responder change. Put a breakpoint in your delegate method and see the call stack..